# What's the use of jsoncallback argument in .getJSON()?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, getjson

In many example code I saw the format of .getJSON() is something like

```
$.getJSON("url?jsoncallback=?", function(data){
...}
```

And at back-end the response is written like

```
$response = $_GET["jsoncallback"]."(".json_encode($orders).")";
echo $reponse
```

I delete "?jsoncallback=?" from the url and $_GET["jsoncallback"] and square brackets at back-end and it seems that everything still works. So what is the use of that jsoncallback stuff indeed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have the `jsoncallback=?` it will just do normal JSON request not JSONP<sup>*</sup>. You can do normal JSON request just fine on your own server or a server that sends [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) headers.

---

<sup>*</sup> forget about JSONP, this is a fancy name for inserting a script element in your document that runs code from a foreign server but with same authorization as your own scripts. The `$_GET["jsoncallback"]`, makes it a javascript function call like this:

```
fn({"data": "value"});
```

This is the code in a script like `<script src="http://foreign.org/data?jsoncallback=fn"></script>`. As you can see, that's Javascript, not JSON. With this, foreign.org (or someone hacking them) can change their script to do anything with authorization on your page, so be careful when using "JSONP" and prefer CORS JSON.

Answer (score 2):

The callback name is used for [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), which is a way to circumvent the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: So is it necessary to add jsoncallback when I use .getJSON()? Since I did not see any difference when I use .getJSON without jsoncallback.

Answer (score 1):

JSON callback can be used to display cross domain data with jQuery. JSONP is used to make cross domain calls since it's not allowed by the same origin policy. Check out the example below.

http://www.9lessons.info/2009/12/display-cross-domain-data-json-callback.html